# Как сделать фильтр по списку из ManyToMany?

Tags: django

Есть модель с полем `ManyToMany`. Из `POST` запроса получаю список `pk` записей которые к `ManyToMany` привязываются. Именно `pk` объекта, который к ManyToMany привязан.
Мне нужно получить только те записи которые нашлись в этой модели. Так их ищу:

```
json_request = json.loads(request.body)
exists_list = json_request['addId']
exists_list.append(json_request['mainId'])
print(exists_list)
try:
    exists_result = LinkedData.objects.filter(many__in=exists_list)
    print(exists_result) >>> 5, 823, 186, 585        
    return HttpResponse(exists_result)
except LinkedData.DoesNotExist:
    return HttpResponse('ok')
```

В записи `ManyToMany` такие `pk`:

`5, 823, 186, 585`

В `exists_list`:

`[83, 663, 853, 5]`

`exists_result` содержит следующие записи:

`5, 823, 186, 585`

То-есть он берет не только те объекты, которые есть в exists_list (тело `POST` запроса). Пока придумал перебирать `QuerySet` и искать совпадения с `exists_list`, и то чего нет в `exists_list` удалять из `QuerySet`. Может есть мение костыльный способ сделать все как нужно?
Модели:

```
class LinkedData(models.Model):
    many = models.ManyToManyField(
        ObjectDataFull,
        related_name='many_related',
        verbose_name='Много'
    )

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'build_analyzer_linked_data'

    def __str__(self):
        return u', '.join([str(a.pk) for a in self.many.all()])


class LinkedInfo(models.Model):
    linked_data = models.ForeignKey(
        LinkedData,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='linked_data_related'
    )
    full = models.ForeignKey(
        ObjectDataFull,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='unsorted_related'
    )

    main = models.BooleanField(
        default=False,
        null=False,
    )

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'build_analyzer_linked_info'
```

И можно ли как-то это в одну строку объединить:

```
exists_list = json_request['addId']
exists_list.append(json_request['mainId'])
```

?
Когда так делаю:

```
exists_list = json_request['addId'].append(json_request['mainId'])
```

получаю `exists_list is None >>> True`

`JSON` выглядит так:

```
{
    "mainId": 5,
    "addId": [83, 663, 853]
}
```

Comment: а скиньте модели, пожалуйста

Comment: @ZaArs обновил вопрос

Comment: queryset из объектов какого типа хотите получить?

Comment: @ZaArs pk записей из `ObjectDataFull`, которые есть в `LinkedData` и в `exists_list`

Comment: правильно понимаю, что Queryset из ObjectDataFull, которые хранятся ВО ВСЕХ LinkedData или вы передаете id именно относящихся к ObjectDataFull ? Если да, то сразу же дам ответ

Comment: @ZaArs передаю id именно относящихся к ObjectDataFull.
Только что вот что написал:
`exists_result = ObjectDataFull.objects.filter(
                Q(id__in=exists_list)
                & Q(many_related__linked_data_related__full__in=exists_list)
            ).distinct() `
вроде правильно работает.

Comment: ну почти правильно. если в ExistsList только id ObjectDataFull, то достаточно `ObjectDataFull.objects.filter(id__in=exists_list)`

Comment: @ZaArs так мне нужно получить то, что и в LinkedData тоже присутствует.

Comment: ок. но & и Q() лишние, можете указать через запятую

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Так нужно делать:

```
try:
    exists_result = ObjectDataFull.objects.filter(id__in=exists_list,
                                                  many_related__linked_data_related__full__in=exists_list).distinct()  # мб можно оптимизировать
    serializer = ObjectSerializer(exists_result, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
except ObjectDataFull.DoesNotExist:
    pass
```